# .NET - Identity does not contain a definition for the custom field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a identity project, I am now trying to create an endpoint for getting the user profile. I want every profile to have a profile image.

I added the custom field in a new model class called `User` like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string? ProfileImage { get; set; }
    }
```

I also added in my `startup.cs`

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And also in the `AppDbContext`

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {

        public AppDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

I also have AutoMapper to map my UserDto with the User class.

However, in my AuthController where I am trying to create an endpoint to fetch the User with Id I get an error that IdentityUser does not contain a definition for ProfileImage.

```
[HttpGet("getUser/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetCurrentUser(string id)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            var model = new UserDto()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.Email,
                Email = user.Email,
                ProfileImage = user.ProfileImage <--- error on this line
            };

            return Ok(model);
        }
```

What am I missing and what could I do to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: For starters, get rid of the "var" and try substituting an explicit `My.Namespace.User user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);`  Your  "userManager" seems to be returning an "IdentityUser", instead of subclass "User".

Comment: Can you please add your controller's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that I put `IdentityUser` in the `UserManager` and `SignInManager`, instead I should have use my `User` class

I changed from this

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;
      

        public AuthController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, 
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

To this

```
private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> signInManager;
       
        public AuthController(UserManager<User> userManager, 
            SignInManager<User> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }
```